# Flink Metric user variable

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am playing with FLink Metric (1.7) and I am stuck here :

I have one flink job who deal with [user variables](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html#user-variables) to expose couple of custom business metrics via the prometheus reporter like :

- number of Protobuf messages processed by customer_id AND by country and by datacenter.
- number of dollars spend ( stored on a variable in a Protobuf messages ) by customer_id AND by country and by type.
- etc..

the target is to have a prometheus data like this :

`<job>_<task>_<operator>_my_data_income{website_id="1",country="fr",dc="EUROPE"} 42`

what I did is that :

```java
public class MyMetricSink extends RichSinkFunction<AbstractASLogMetricEntity> {
    @Override
    public void invoke(AbstractASLogMetricEntity value, Context context) {
        getRuntimeContext()
            .getMetricGroup()
            .addGroup(  "website_id" , value.getCustomer() )
            .addGroup( "country" , value.getCountry() )
            .addGroup(  "dc" , value.getDatacenter() )
            .addGroup( "my_data" )
            .counter( "income" )
            .inc( value.getIncome() );

     }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) {       
    }
}
```

**That dont work** => Warning log : `"Name collision: Group already contains a Metric with the name..."` from the AbstractMetricGroup class.

In order to make that work correctly , I need to create all the counters on the `open` method first.
So I will have a cartesian product of my custom metrics to expose.
Could be 1.2 Millions of counters stored on a HashMap probably..

Do you guys have any suggestions to avoid that?
It's the correct way to do it ?
it's possible to do what I want by using a work arround somewhere ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat outside the bounds of what flink's metric system was designed to support. Some folks who have tried running with that many metrics have reported having problems.

Depending on what you are ultimately trying to accomplish, you might consider using an influxdb sink connected to prometheus (or grafana), or maybe an elasticsearch sink. Or perhaps queryable state is a better fit.

Comment: Hi David, and thx to you answer. I am sure that what you said could work. If someone have the same problem, here, what I did . 
I used the pushGateway exporter ( to be get rid of HTTPServer ) Then, dev on my Flink jobs my own MetricRegisteric registered to another pushgateway , I re-used some code to have a SchedulerThread in order to push the data evrey X seconds. That's made the trick, I got my custom metric + flink exporter metrics.